# Can't create Windows Login's on a case sensitive SQL Server 2005 Instance - MSG 15401

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, case-sensitive

I need to create 3 logins on a SQL Server 2005 instance:

- DOMAIN\aaa
- DOMAIN\bbb
- DOMAIN\ccc

However two of them (aaa and bbb) fail with the following error:

> Msg 15401, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Windows NT user or group
>   'DOMAIN\aaa' not found. Check the name again.

When I try to add them with `DOMAIN\AAA` and `DOMAIN\BBB` it works.

What is causing this strange case sensitive behaviour? And how can I add all accounts
lower case?

I found a KB article from Microsoft for the 15401 error, but nothing in there explains this behaviour.

Comment: I had the same issue once. I think I was able to change the collation at the DB level and this fixed the problem. Let me check the server again, and I will let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You chose a case sensitive [collation when installing SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260.aspx)

You will have "CS" in this result:

```
 SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')
```

You either live with it or [rebuild the master database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143269%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Well since it's a commercial product, this is not my choice and I can't go and change the collaction. I try to understand where this behaviour comes from and especially why some login's seem to be different from others.